# C# EF Generic Class Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I made a GenericClass to retrieve data from the database, this works fine.
But the .Include(propname) does not work. I have added the code I have tried below.

**GenericClass**

```
public T GetItemByQuery<T>(Func<T, bool> query, List<string> NavigationProperties = null) where T : EntityObject
    {
        try
        {
            using (Entities context = new Entities())
            {
                var ObjectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
                if (NavigationProperties != null)
                {
                    foreach (string prop in NavigationProperties)
                    {
                        ObjectSet.Include(prop).AsParallel().ToList();
                    }
                }
                return ObjectSet.Where(query).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }
    }
```

**Code**

```
Category category = bController.GetItemByQuery(new Func<Category, bool>(x => x.Active), new List<string> { "Products" });
```

**Debugger**

**Shop = null as property**
[image: Shop = null]

**This is shopUrls > _relationships > _relationships > [0]**
[image]
I use EF6

Can someone tell me why category.Products is null?

Thanks.

Comment: You mention `category.Products` in the text, while in the images you highlight `Shop`. Now it's unclear which code produced the images.

Answer (score 0):

Please to try use an approach like in my example, it's works as expected and also by my opinion the `Expression` better then List of strings.

```
public virtual T GetById<T>(int id,  params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) where T : BaseEntity<int>
    {
       var result = Context.Set<T>();

       IQueryable<T> query = null;
       foreach (var property in includeProperties)
       {
           query = query == null ? result.Include(property) : query.Include(property);
       }

      return query == null ? result.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Id == id) :
                              query.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);

    }
```

Example: // Will generate query with include

```
 var model = Repository.GetById<Pan>(id, p => p.PanEmvTags.Select(t => t.EmvTag));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong here:

- `Func<T, bool> query`. This should be `Expression<Func<T, bool>> query`. If you pass it as `Func` the query (the `ObjectSet`) is cast to `IEnumerable` before it is executed. This means that the predicate (`query`) is not translated to SQL. The whole set is retrieved from the database first, then the predicate is applied as LINQ to objects.
- `ObjectSet.Include(prop).AsParallel().ToList();`. This executes the query for each include property. In stead, you should *extend* the ObjectSet by each navigation property: `ObjectSet = ObjectSet.Include(prop);`. `ObjectSet` must be cast to `IQueryable` to make this work.

So the method should look like this:

```
public T GetItemByQuery<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query, params string[] NavigationProperties) where T : EntityObject
{
    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        var ObjectSet = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AsQueryable();
        foreach (string prop in NavigationProperties)
        {
            ObjectSet = ObjectSet.Include(prop);
        }
        return ObjectSet.Where(query).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result, i edit my post with pictures of the debugger

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what you did there.